# Subtract date with format DD-MMM-YYYY

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have date in format **DD-MMM-YYYY**

I want to subtract this date from current date which is also in the same format.

How do I **subtract** them from each other ?

```
var complaint_date =  15-JUL-2020
var current_date = 21-JUL-2020
var duration  = current_date - complaint_date // this is not working
```

Comment: Break it down in to steps. First accept that you can't subtract strings from each other, you have to convert your string into a date object. You can choose to use the native javascript Date object or a library like moment.js. Once you have your 2 dates then use one of the operations. It is still not very clear to me what you are trying to accomplish though. Generally you want a time span like X days or X months etc when looking at the difference between dates. The end result might also make you pick a library over the native Date object. So follow the advice above and give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot subtract strings from each other. If you want to subtract dates you need to convert the strings to `Date` object.

```js
var complaint_date =  new Date("15-JUL-2020")
var current_date = new Date("21-JUL-2020")
var duration  = current_date - complaint_date
console.log(duration) // diff in milliseconds
console.log(Math.round(Math.abs((duration) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)))) // diff in days
```

Comment: sorry for being noob, How do i get the result in days ? dividing it by milliseconds in a day ?  86400000

Comment: @user2828442 yes it was the key :+1